# How to create a constant vector by variant arrays of numbers?

Tags: matlab

I have a vector ("d") which I want to place it's content to a matrix ("dis"), I have the problem to create "dis" matrix. "dis" should be like

```
dis=[
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
    0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
    0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1];

n=[0,0;1,0;2,0;3,0;4,0;5,0;6,0;7,0;8,0;9,0;10,0;11,0;12,0];
d=pdist(n,'euclidean');
l=length(n)-1;
dis=[];
for k=1:length(n)-1
    dis=[dis;d((k-1)*l-(k*((k-1)/2))+k):d(k*l-((k+1)*k/2)+k)];

end
```

Comment: Look at [squareform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/squareform.html)

Comment: Or use `bsxfun`: `triu(bsxfun(@minus,(1:12),(0:11).'))`.

Comment: Or `cumsum(cummax(eye(12))).'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not padding dis with the zeros.

You can replace

```
dis=[];
for k=1:length(n)-1
    dis=[dis;d((k-1)*l-(k*((k-1)/2))+k):d(k*l-((k+1)*k/2)+k)];
end
```

with

```
dis = zeros(l);
for k=1:l
    dis(k,k:end) = d((k-1)*l-(k*((k-1)/2))+k):d(k*l-((k+1)*k/2)+k)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `squareform` form @beaker comment above, you can write:

```
dis = triu(squareform(d));
dis = dis(1:length(dis)-1,2:length(dis));
```

Does this solves the problem?